# Definition of Sheaf of Rational Functions on Integral Scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Given an integral (i.e. irreducible and reduced) scheme $X$ of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$.
We can consider $X$ as a variety.
On a cover $\{U_i\}$ of affine varieties, $U_i \simeq V(I_i)$ for $I_i \subset k[x_1,\dots ,x_n]$, the field of rational functions $K(U_i)$ is given as the quotient field of the coordinate ring $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I_i$.
We may consider the sheaf of rational functions on $U_i$, which just gives the field of rational functions on every open.
This should define a sheaf on all of $X$.

Given an arbitrary scheme $X$.
In the section on Cartier Divisors in Hartshorne, there is a very complicated definition for the sheaf of rational functions on $X$ given.
The text states:
*"On an arbitrary scheme, the sheaf $\mathcal{K}$ replaces the concept of function field of an integral scheme."*

> What is a good definition for the sheaf of rational functions on an arbitrary integral scheme?
>   That is, a definition not as specific as the first one, but not as general as the second one.

The question arose when studying the chapter on line bundles on curves in Gathmann's lecture notes.
There the *sheaf of rational functions* on a curve $X$ is used without prior introduction.
Does the word *curve* imply that the scheme is a variety?
I always thought of a curve as any one-dimensional scheme.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $X$ is an integral scheme, then $X$ has a unique generic point - the point associated to the zero ideal in any open affine neighbourhood. We can define the function field of $X$ to be the local ring at the generic point.

The sheaf of rational functions $\mathcal K_X$ on $X$ is a constant sheaf. The group of sections over *any* non-empty open set $U$ is the function field of $X$.

For practical purposes, this information is of little use unless we are able to identify $\mathcal O_X$ as a subsheaf of $\mathcal K_X$. We can do this as follows. First, we cover $X$ with a collection of open affines. In any open affine subset ${\rm Spec } A \subset X$, the generic point is associated to the zero ideal $(0) \subset {\rm Spec } A$, and the function field is the localisation $A_{(0)}$. Given a point in ${\rm Spec}A$, represented by a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$, there is a natural inclusion morphism $i_{\mathfrak p} : A_{\mathfrak p} \to A_{(0)}$. For any open set $U \subset {\rm Spec}A$, we can define $\mathcal O_X (U) \subset \mathcal K_X(U)$ as the subring of $A_{(0)}$ consisting of all elements in $A_{(0)}$ that are in the image of $i_{\mathfrak p}$ for all $\mathfrak p \subset U$. If $U$ intersects more than one open affine in our affine cover, then $\mathcal O_X(U)$ is the subring of the function field consisting of elements that obey this criterion  in each open affine that $U$ intersects.

Comment: Thank you very much. The important revelation for me was "If you like, you may think of the function field [...] as the quotient field of the ring of regular functions on any open set." That is the characterization most easy to understand for me.

Comment: Really sorry, but I realised I screwed up terribly! This statement just isn't true. For example, consider a projective variety. The only global regular functions are the constant functions! The quotient field of this ring of constants is still the constants! That clearly isn't right.

Comment: I hope this is correct now, or as close as possible to being correct. Once again, I'm really sorry about the previous answer. If you think there is anything wrong with this description, then I would appreciate it if you would let me know.

Comment: Your definition sure seems reasonable, but you already had me with your first suggestion, so I am certainly not the right person to judge whether it is correct. Where did you get that definition from? It is clear that it reduces to the ordinary "sheaf of rational functions" (i.e. the function field) for varieties. How does it relate to the more general definition on arbitrary schemes? (No need to write down a proof here, as I have not even understood the definition on arbitrary schemes yet. But a reference would be much appreciated) Also no need to be sorry, I appreciate your effort to help.

Comment: Let $\mathcal K_X^{\rm wrong}$ be defined so that $\mathcal K_X^{\rm wrong}(U)$ is the quotient field of $\mathcal O_X(U)$. This thing is a _presheaf_! The sheaf $\mathcal K_X$ is the _sheafification_ of the presheaf $\mathcal K_X^{\rm wrong}$. In plain English, a section in $\mathcal K_X (U)$ is a function that can be expressed as ratios of regular functions _on local patches inside $U$._ My mistake was that I forgot to sheafify the presheaf. :-(

Comment: For example, consider $\mathbb P^1 = {\rm Proj} \ k[x,y]$, and take $U$ to be the whole of $\mathbb P^1$. The rational function $x / y$ is a legimate rational function on $U$. Yet the only global regular functions on $U$ are the constants, and $x / y$ is not a ratio of constants. However, $x / y = 1/(1 + y/x)$ on the patch $\{ x \neq 0 \}$ and $x / y = (x/y)/1$ on the patch $\{ y \neq 0 \}$, so $x / y$ can be expressed as ratios of regular functions _on local patches within $U$._

Comment: So how can we see that the definition in my revised answer agrees with the sheafification of the presheaf in Hartshorne? The key observation is that, on an integral scheme, (i) all non-empty open sets are dense, and (ii) cancellation works in algebraic equations. From these two facts, you can show that once you specify what a rational function looks like on one small patch, this uniquely determines how the rational function looks on all other patches.

Comment: In the example above: once I tell you that my rational functions looks like $1/(1+y/x)$ on the patch $\{ x \neq 0\}$, the only possibility is that the rational function looks like $(x/y) / 1$ on the other patch. There is no alternative.

Comment: To wrap up: once you realise that sections in the sheafification of $\mathcal K_X(U)$ are uniquely specified by how they look on any one little patch (rather than having to specify how they look on every patch), this insight makes it much easier to prove that there is a bijection between the function field and the ring of sections.

Comment: Alright, that clears things up for me, thank you very much!

Comment: Haha I even managed to screw up that example! The rational function $x / y$ can be written as the ratio $1/(y/x)$ on the patch $\{ x \neq 0 \}$, not $1/(1+y/x)$!  And the final sentence should say "once you realise that any section in $\mathcal K_X(U)$...". Finally, check out this wikipedia page:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_field_(scheme_theory)#Simple_cases :-)